# syslog-ng network() destination doesn't like transport("tcp")

Tags: linux, syslog-ng

I have installed `syslog-ng` v3.5.6 to the `Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)`:

```
# syslog-ng --version
syslog-ng 3.5.6
Installer-Version: 3.5.6
Revision: 3.5.6-2+b1 [@416d315] (Debian/unstable)
Compile-Date: Oct  1 2014 18:23:11
Available-Modules: confgen,basicfuncs,afstomp,afsocket-tls,csvparser,syslogformat,affile,cryptofuncs,redis,afsql,afsmtp,afsocket-notls,afamqp,afprog,afsocket,system-source,dbparser,json-plugin,afmongodb,linux-kmsg-format,tfgeoip,afuser
Enable-Debug: off
Enable-GProf: off
Enable-Memtrace: off
Enable-IPv6: on
Enable-Spoof-Source: on
Enable-TCP-Wrapper: on
Enable-Linux-Caps: on
Enable-Pcre: on
```

Now trying to configure network destination:

```
destination d_netsrv {
  network(
    transport("tcp")
    ip-protocol(4) ip(10.3.2.1) port(601)
    so-keepalive(yes) keep-alive(yes)
    flags(syslog-protocol)
  );
};
```

But `syslog-ng` doesn't like [transport()](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.5-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html-single/index.html#idp46435348803872) option:

```
# syslog-ng --syntax-only
Error parsing afsocket, syntax error, unexpected KW_TRANSPORT, expecting LL_IDENTIFIER or LL_STRING in /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf at line 53, column 5:

    transport("tcp")
    ^^^^^^^^^

syslog-ng documentation: http://www.balabit.com/support/documentation/?product=syslog-ng
mailing list: https://lists.balabit.hu/mailman/listinfo/syslog-ng
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
destination d_netsrv {
  network( "10.3.2.1" port(601) transport(tcp) so-keepalive(yes) keep-alive(yes) flags(syslog-protocol)
  );
};
```

or if it not works:

```
destination d_netsrv {
  network( "10.3.2.1" port(601) transport(tcp) flags(syslog-protocol) );
};
```

The destination address does not have `ip()`, and you do not need `ip-protocol(4)` as it is the default.

See [syslog-ng Example 7.28. Using the network() driver](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-network.html)

Comment: In general that was documentation problem. [Docs](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.5-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html-single/index.html#configuring-destinations-network) for the version that I have installed indeed show example with `network(ip() port() transport())`, while in later docs they have `network("ip_addr" port() transport())`.